# Cast from Integer to Character without using unsafe conversion

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, integer, character

I have to write a method that has a parameter of type Integer and has to return an object of type Character.
If the value of the given parameter is presentable as a Character object,
Return it as a Character. Else return null.

My task is poorly formulated it says: "Unsafe conversions (e.g. from int to char) are not allowed in your code" I suppose it is not unsafe but also not allowed somehow?

My Code so far:

```
public Character methodName (Integer i) {

        if (i >= 0 && i <= Character.MAX_VALUE) {
            return Character.valueOf((char) i.intValue());   //unsafe conversion
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I tried fixing it by any means but just could not come up with an solution not using the unsafe conversion, thank you very much in advance for helping!

Solution to this weird formulated task:

```
public Character methodName (Integer i) {

        if (i >= 0 && i <= Character.MAX_VALUE) {
            return (Character.toChars(i)[0]); //<- solution
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: That's not an unsafe conversion ... in any sense that I am aware of.  (Please explain more clearly what you think the problem with that conversion is.  What do you think is unsafe about it?)

Comment: Hey, so the exact words in my task are as following: " Unsafe conversions (e.g. from int to char) are not allowed in your code" @StephenC

Comment: Well I'm afraid you have been given a nonsensical task.  Ask your teacher to explain to you what is unsafe about that conversion.  Show them your code.

Comment: I'd argue the range check should make the conversion safe though - the question is rather poorly formulated.

Comment: Exactly.  And even if you didn't do the range check, the potential truncation that occurs when you cast `int` to `char` is not "unsafe" as far as the Java language is concerned.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to find a different solution for the whole day, the whole task is poorly formulated. Besides the fact that it is safe, is there a way around of casting like this ? I am going to talk to him about that ...

Comment: `char[] chrs = Character.toChars(i); if (chrs.length == 1) return chrs[0]; return null;`.

Comment: SO my teacher said it is indeed unsafe, because the value range of int is 2^32 and of char is 2^16 @StephenC

Comment: @JohannesKuhn so i talked to my teacher and he said it is indeed forbidden to cast via (char) cast because of what I said in my previous comment.
So the .toChar method is also using this type of cast so should also be forbidden

Comment: Well ... by your teacher's own logic (!) if you test that `i` is in the range 0 to 65535, `(char) i` is no longer unsafe.

Comment: toChars is safe. It won't produce unexpected results. It takes a codepoint as input (which can be in the range 0-0x10FFFF) and outputs a char array that contains 1 or 2 chars. There can be no unsafe overflow or whatever.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yeah I also think that is the only solution that fulfill all the desires of the task, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind

```
  if (i >= 0 && i <= Character.MAX_VALUE) {
       return Character.valueOf((char) i.intValue());
  }
```

is completely safe according to your teacher's definition of "safe".

> SO my teacher said it is indeed unsafe, because the value range of int is 2^32 and of char is 2^16.

The `if` test ensures that you only cast `i.intValue()` to a `char` when `i` is in the required (safe) range.

The flipside is that if a *provably correct* range check is not sufficient to make this "safe" enough for your teacher, then AFAIK there isn't a "safe" solution.  All other less direct solutions also entail an explicit or implicit range check in some form ... and will therefore *also* be "unsafe".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but yeah you are totally right as he has formulated this task wrong. I am quite sure that he just wanted us to find an other way to solve it, as he just responded to my explanations: " I should search the library of Character "

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion is safe here.

- You're checking if the int is in the Character range
- Then you cast using a builtin method

There might be another way but it's trickier and weird:

```
String iStr = Integer.toString(i.intValue())
char c = iStr.charAt(0)
Character crt = Character.valueOf(c)
```

I repeat myself but your approach is more than fine... I don't understand what does your teacher expect from you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am so confused though, as my task is poorly formulated it says: "Unsafe conversions (e.g. from int to char) are not allowed in your code" I suppose it is not unsafe but also not allowed somehow?

Comment: @snow_white: Edit your question and add that statement as quote. There is a lot of confusion here what you mean by "unsafe conversion".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn was not a 100% what you meant with that, is my question now better formulated?